# Convert arrays datatype in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, types

So, I am trying to convert the datatype of an array inside a column of dataframe in python from float to int.

```
>>> df
       arr
0   [1.0,2.0]
1   [NaN, 3.0]
```

The desired output is :

```
>>> df
       arr
0   [1 , 2]
1   [3]
```

Comment: That `arr` column is object dtype.  It can contain lists, numpy arrays, strings or anything else.  That column does not neatly fit the `pandas` 'table' concept.   You have to process each object/cell of that column separately.

Answer (score 2):

- `NaN` evaluates as a `float` and will cause `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` if you try to convert it to an `int`

  - Us [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to test if a value is `np.nan`
- Convert other values to `int` as shown in the list comprehension below.

```py
import numpy as np

df['arr'].apply(lambda x: [int(v) for v in x if not np.isnan(v)])
```